# dynamically adding a method to a module in Ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

so I have a bunch of code that looks like this:

```
module Foo
  def detect(this_message)
    #check for timeout
    if Time.now > instance_variable_get("@#{this_message}_timeout".to_sym)
      @state_machine.method("#{this_message}_timed_out".to_sym).call
      return
    end
    yield
    record
  rescue StandardError => e
    # retry on exception
    @state_machine.method("#{this_message}_retry".to_sym).call(exception: e)
  end

  # a bunch of these
  def detect_blah
    detect(:blah) do
      # detection code
      @state_machine.method("#{this_message}_detected".to_sym).call
      # or failed, you get the idea
    end
  end
end

...
class Bar
  include Foo
  # more stuff
end
```

I want to eliminate the `def detect_blah` declaration. I want to just say `detect(:blah)` and have it add a `detect_blah` method dynamically, that includes all the same processing as above, including the yielded block.

I've tried a few permutations of `define_method`.

- If I just call `define_method` from `detect` I get NoMethodError, which makes sense because we're calling detect at module construction time and the module (class?) can't call its own methods when it isn't built (right?).
- If I add it to a different module and include that module in this one I get the same error.
- I've seen code that does `self.class.send(:define_method, method_name, method_definition)` but I don't think I'm getting far enough for that to work.
- maybe there's a way to do this via the metaclass... for classes. Not seeing how to do it for a module. Hm.

Is there a reasonable way to do what I want to do?

Comment: `declare_method` is not a `method` but `define_method` as mentioned is a `method`. The rest of your code does not really make sense to me e.g. you are calling `yield` and yielding the actual block rather than yielding too it?

Comment: good catch with `declare_method`. Corrected. Also, Ruby has about five ways to pass a block to a method, and I found the most obscure one. Also corrected--no need to mention `block` at all. Does that help?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. If you call `detect(:foo)` and `detect(:bar)` is that intended to create methods `foo` and `bar` that perform the same operations and have the same return values? btw, you missed correcting one `declare_method`.

Comment: That would create `detect_foo` and `detect_bar` methods that have the same operations/return values, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
module Foo
  def detect(this_message, &block)
    # boilerplate stuff using instance_variable_get(blah) and
    # calling methods on instance variables...
    yield block
    # more boilerplate stuff
    self.class.send(:define_method, "detect_#{this_message.to_s}") do
        puts "This is templated detection code for #{this_message.to_s}"
        # blah
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In a comment on the question the OP made it clear that all the methods created would perform the same operations and return the same values. This means that all the instance methods created after the first can simply be made *aliases* of the original instance method. (It's not clear why doing that would be helpful, but that's beside the point.) In the module `Foo` I have called that original instant method `boilerplate`. We could write the following:

```
module Foo
  def detect(method_name)
    self.class.send(:alias_method, method_name, :boilerplate)
  end

  def boilerplate
    yield "Spud"
  end
end

class Bar
  include Foo
end
```

See [Module#alias_method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Module.html#method-i-alias_method). We need to use `send` because `alias_method` is a private method.

We may now write the following.

```
Bar.instance_methods && [:detect, :boilerplate]
  #=> [:detect, :boilerplate]

b = Bar.new
b.detect(:say)
b.detect("hey")

Bar.instance_methods(false)
  #=> [:say, :hey]

b.say { |name| "My name is #{name}" }
  #=> "My name is Spud"
b.hey { |name| "My name is #{name}" }
  #=> "My name is Spud"
```

Comment: I made my code less abstract and closer to the code I am actually writing. I have other code that initiates long processes over a network, and here I am polling to see if they finish before a timeout. I have a state machine that persists (coded elsewhere) in case my process dies while waiting, so I can wake up again knowing where I was.

Comment: Have you tried using AASM gem? Its a state machine for ruby classes and offers detection methods for each state. https://github.com/aasm/aasm

Comment: @sakurashinken, no I'm not familiar with it, but I confess that in light of John's comment I don't understand the question, so cannot determine if the gem would be helpful here.

Comment: @sakurashinksen yes, aasm is the state machine being used by this object. It didn't seem relevant to my question so I didn't mention it here.